# Application is not working with wifi on android device

Tags: android, facebook, twitter, wifi

I am making an application in android which integrates twitter and facebook logins and save the logged user info. It is working fine in device with GPRS. But when I am trying to run the application with wifi it gives exception as below.

For **Twitter: "Server error"**

For **Facebook: "DialogError"**

please give me some hint to solve this problem.

Comment: "please give me some hint to solve this problem." - Please show some code. Show what you're trying to do and the error messages from LogCat.

Comment: Can you access Facebook through the stock android browser over wifi? Next question, can you access the https (the http-secure of facebook) through the stock android browser over wifi?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use permission

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_SETTINGS" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
```

I think u off ur WIFI in phone.

Comment: Sir still it is not working and I also added <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.wifi"/> But the problem is same

Comment: @stiffler, What does logcat say?